# How select data from Multi Database in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two tables. First table `Product` contains the columns `product id`, `name` and `Department_id`. The second table `Departments` contains columns `Department id` and `name`.

I want to create a page to insert to Products details in Product table and I want a combo box should be populated with Departments name at this page.

Comment: Improve your question by adding examples

Comment: I mean when open the page to insert new product the combo box fill by names the Department You understand me ?

Comment: ambiguous question.

Comment: Is your view strongly bind to any model?

Comment: no not a single word

Comment: Please take a moment to read this so we can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not clear to us. But somehow i figured it out what you want..

**Model classes**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class Departments
{
    public int DepartmentID{get;set;}
    public string DepartmentName {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
          List<Departments> deps = new List<Departments>();

        deps.Add(new Departments() {DepartmentID=1, DepartmentName="IT"});
        deps.Add(new Departments() { DepartmentID = 2, DepartmentName = "HR" });

        ViewBag.lstDeps = deps;

        return View(new Product());
    }
```

**View**

```
    @model HelloWorldMvcApp.Product
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
   IEnumerable<HelloWorldMvcApp.Departments> CDrop = ViewBag.lstDeps;


        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var c in CDrop)
        {
            SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
            i.Text = c.DepartmentName.ToString();
            i.Value = c.DepartmentID.ToString();
            selectList.Add(i);
        }

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>

                @Html.DropDownList("DEpartments", new SelectList(selectList, "Value","Text"))

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductName, new {@class="form-control"}) 

                    </div>

                }

                <br/><br/>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**<kbd>[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9cupz7)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

you can create a model that combine Product and Departments and pass it from the controller to the view.

---

for example :

```
public class CompositeModel
{
     public Product product { get; set;}
     public Department department { get; set;}
}
```

hope this helps.